# understanding of the parametric transversality theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is the following correct (including under which conditions on $S,M$ including existance of boundary), and if so, which (with a reference please!) transversality theorem implies it exactly?

Given a smooth map from a product manifold $\phi: S \times M \rightarrow N$, if $Q \leq N$ is a submanifold and $\phi \pitchfork Q$ then, for almost all $s \in S$, $\phi_s(p):=\phi(s,p)$ has $\phi_s \pitchfork Q$ also.

Here $\pitchfork$ represents transversalilty.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of manifolds with corners it is the content of Lemma 6.4 p52 of P. Michor's book "Manifolds of differentiable mappings".

Edit1: In the case of manifolds without boundary, you can look at "Differential topology" M. W. Hirsch chapter 3.

Comment: How about without boundary, or corners etc..